# Google Graph error Uncaught (in promise) Error: Column header row must be an array

Tags: javascript, php, json, charts

When I try to select an option from the list of districts the onchange run the following method:

```
showAgeDistributionGraph: function() {
            let e                   =   document.getElementById("TxtAgeGroup");
            let txtAgeGroup         =   e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            let url                 =   'backend/core/loadCasesByAgeGroup.php';

            var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: url,                 
                data: {
                    ds: txtAgeGroup
                },
                dataType: 'json', 
            }).done(function(jsonData) {
                google.charts.load('current', { 
                    packages: ['corechart']                 
            }).then(function () {
                drawChart(jsonData);})
            }); 

            google.charts.load('current', {
                    packages: ['corechart']
                }).then(function () {
                    drawChart(jsonData);
                });            
        }
```

Once the above code is processed the drawChart function is executed

```
    function drawChart(jsonData){
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
            jsonData
        ], false);

        console.log(jsonData);

        var options = {
            title: 'Cases By Age Group',
            width: 900,
            height: 400,
            bar: {groupWidth: "80%"},
            legend: { position: "bottom" },
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chartContainer'));

        chart.draw(data, options);      
    }
```

The PHP code which is executed in the background is the following:

```
        // STATISTICS (GRAPHS)
        public function districtPopulationGraph($ds)
        {
            $sql    = "call `new_CasesAgeDistributionChart`(?);";
            $stmt   = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute([$ds]);

            if ($stmt->rowCount()>0) 
            {
                $data[] = ["Age","Total Clients"];
                while ($record = $stmt->fetch())
                {

                    // UPDATE TOTALS 
                    $data[]     =   ["GroupA",$record['16-17']];
                    $data[]     =   ["GroupB",$record['18-29']];
                    $data[]     =   ["GroupC",$record['30-49']];
                    $data[]     =   ["GroupD",$record['50-64']];
                    $data[]     =   ["GroupE",$record['65+']];   
                }

                $data_for_chart = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
                return $data_for_chart;                  
            }
```

// Output returned by $data_for_chart is
[["Age","Total Clients"],["GroupA","24"],["GroupB","251"],["GroupC","576"],["GroupD","407"],["GroupE","659"]]

The problem is that the Chart is giving an error of:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Column header row must be an array.

Comment: `"['Age','Total Clients']"` is a _string_, not an array. Get rid of the outer quote marks. Same problem on your `$data[]     =...` lines.

Comment: 0
: 
["Age", "Total Clients"]
1
: 
["GroupA", "80"]
2
: 
["GroupB", "626"]
3
: 
["GroupC", "1334"]
4
: 
["GroupD", "960"]
5
: 
["GroupE", "1178"]

jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:299 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Column header row must be an array.

Comment: You should also remove `implode(",\n",$data)`...again, you seem to be converting everything back to a string when, as far as I can see, it needs to be an array of arrays. There's also no need for newlines everywhere. I get the impression you're trying to build JSON by hand _and_ present it nicely visually. Presentation is pointless because it's being consumed by code, not a person, and building JSON by hand is an error-prone and dubious business. `json_encode()` exists for a reason. Build your data structure as a normal PHP variable, not a string, and encode it as JSON when you output it.

Comment: After I posted the question I changed it to:
$data_for_chart = json_encode($data);

Comment: You haven't shown where the data goes when it's returned from the `districtPopulationGraph`  function but presumably it goes to somewhere in the PHP which echoes it as the response to the AJAX request. At that point of echoing, the array you generate should be encoded as JSON using json_encode. Just return an array from districtPopulationGraph...don't encode it until the actual moment of output.

Comment: `After I posted the question `...you should always [edit] the question to show any changes you make, so that everyone is looking at the right version of the code.

Comment: P.S. `['Age','Total Clients'], ['GroupA',80], ['GroupB',626], ['GroupC',1334], ['GroupD',960], ['GroupE',1178] - valid json` ...that is **not** valid JSON. JSON doesn't allow string values to be single-quoted. Also it's missing any outer brackets to group it all together as a single coherent JSON object/array. You can paste your JSON into tools such as jsonlint.com to validate it, but - as I said above - you shouldn't try to generate JSON by hand to begin with, because you end up with exactly these kinds of silly problems which are entirely avoidable by just using json_encode.

Comment: var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    ds: txtAgeGroup
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false
            }).responseText;

jsonData will retrieve the data from the PHP backend and information will then be passed to drawChart(jsonData)

Comment: the output of jsonData in console is the following
0: ["Age", "Total Clients"]
1: ["GroupA", "80"]
2: ["GroupB", "626"]
3: ["GroupC", "1334"]
4: ["GroupD", "960"]
5: ["GroupE", "1178"]

Comment: It looks like you're still potentially outputting strings. Did you make the changes to the `$data[] = ...` lines as I mentioned in my first comment? It's not shown in your code update.

Comment: I changed them now, but, the problem is still there ... Column header row must be an array.

Comment: Thanks. Now please show the raw output of the json_encode command (not the console.log version once it's become a JS object)

Comment: The response from the json_encode is as follows:
[["Age","Total Clients"],["GroupA","24"],["GroupB","251"],["GroupC","576"],["GroupD","407"],["GroupE","659"]]

Comment: Looks like your `jsonData` already contains the proper array format - and your mistake is, that you are wrapping it into an additional level of square brackets in your `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable` call ...

Comment: Was just about to write the same thing. Try `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData, false);` (i.e. without the additional `[...]`)

Comment: @CBroe once I removed the square brackets the error is:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Data for arrayToDataTable is not an array.

Comment: So it is _not_ an array then, but a string containing JSON. Likely due to the fact, that you are explicitly accessing the `responseText` property of your AJAX object there. You can specify `dataType: 'json'` all day long, that doesn't mean jQuery will modify the actual `responseText` property, that _stays_ a string value.

Comment: So is there any solution to fix this issue? I never encountered this problem and seems so problematic.

Comment: Well the simplest fix would be to `JSON.parse(jsonData)`.

Comment: But instead of using deprecated async:false and accessing plain responseText directly you really ought to send the request async and handle the response via a callback properly. e.g. `$.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    ds: txtAgeGroup
                },
                dataType: 'json',
            }).done(function(jsonData) {
            google.charts.load('current', {
                    packages: ['corechart']
                }).then(function () {
                    drawChart(jsonData);
                })}); `

Comment: We are there! the only problem is that the value should not be enclosed in quotations.
Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string×

Comment: the output of jsonData is now Age,Total Clients, GroupA, 24, GroupB, 251, GroupC, 576, GroupD, 407, GroupE, 659

Comment: The answer on how to fix the last issue was easy by inserting json_encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) in the backend PHP file.